# Powershell command to remove/replace access/owner rights on all files and folders

Tags: powershell

I'm merging multiple file servers that have been mismanaged for decades into a single large file server. There are about 2 million files in a few thousand folders.

I need to replace the multiple different owners on all the folders and files, remove all user and group rights from all directories, and set my admin group as the owner of all files and folders.

After that is done, I begin the painful process of logically reorganizing the file server and returning rights to the users.

Does anyone know a Powershell command to strip all files/folders of all owners/rights and replace them with a different owner?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The code is shown below about changing ownership. Besides you can find the similar answer [PowerShell Change owner of files and folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22988384/powershell-change-owner-of-files-and-folders)

```
$folder = "\\homeserver\users"
$users = (get-childitem $folder)

Foreach ($user in $users) {
    $acl = Get-Acl $folder\$user
    $acl.SetOwner([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]"$user")
    set-acl $folder\$user $acl
}
```