# Take ownership & Delete Folder Errors

Tags: powershell, file-ownership

So i'm trying to delete a few remote folders but am running into permission issues.

I've tried:

```
Get-ChildItem \\$Comp\c$\eQube-Tools -Force  | Remove-Item  -Recurse
Get-ChildItem \\$Comp\c$\Gecko -Force  | Remove-Item  -Recurse

Remove-Item \\$Comp\c$\eQube-Tools -Force -Recurse
Remove-Item \\$Comp\c$\Gecko -Force -Recurse
```

But that gave me permission errors, So i added:

```
takeown /a /r /d Y /f \\$Comp\c$\eQube-Tools


takeown /a /r /d Y /f \\$Comp\c$\Gecko
```

Only to get:[RemoveItem Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlD3h.png)

About it being not empty.. i was reading that:

```
Remove-Item \\$Comp\c$\eQube-Tools -Force -Recurse
```

would delete the empty folder that:

```
Get-ChildItem \\$Comp\c$\eQube-Tools -Force  | Remove-Item  -Recurse
```

had created.

I did look into the ownership of the folders:[Folder Owner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVqSA.png)
**the only issues i can see is with the owner being the built in Admin Account

**Im open to using:**

```
rmdir (tried using psexec with this, this was my first attempt)
Object.Delete() *this is going to be my next try
```

**My setup is:**

Local Account: Administrator

Win 10 laptop running the code (PSVer 5.1)

on a workgroup

**Remote Units:**
\\ip\C$ i can delete the folders fine this way (once the program has been killed)

Local Account: Administrator

Win 7 Home

Workgroup

PSver 2.0

Comment: That's a .db file, a thumb.db. It's probably in use. Either kill the program that has a handle on it, use handles.exe to see what holding it, or restart the computer then run the command as soon as it comes up.

Comment: Thumbs.db is also hidden by default, so in order to remove these, you must use `-Force`

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure if you and i are on the right way to find your solution here are some questions and suggestions.

1. Are the computers you are trying to access member of an active directory?
   If yes, you might prefer deleting the folder with a GPO. This would work extremely easy if "system" still has permissions. Just create a new GPO and link it to the GPO you need it, and or filter the computer you want to apply to. Open it and go to "Computer configuration" > "settings" > "Windows-Settings" > "Folder" and create a new folder there. Select in the options of this folder "Delete" and check all checkboxes you need (all except the last)
   Just tried it works even if i am not owner and got no permissions - but system needs permission.
2. did you start your PowerShell with highest privileges?
   Depending on how you test this might affect your testing.
3. Can you post your exact error message?
   In some cases, error messages contain helpful information
4. Found that article that might help - could you try that either?
   [PowerShell Change owner of files and folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22988384/powershell-change-owner-of-files-and-folders/22988638)